# How to have confirm password field using play framework case class bind?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.4, playframework-2.5

I have two models:

```
case class User(uid: Option[Int], email: String, password: String, created_at: Timestamp, updated_at: Timestamp)

case class UserProfile(firstname: String, lastname: String, gender: Int, user_id: Int)
```

I am binding it in the form in controller:

```
val date = new Date()
  val currentTimestamp= new Timestamp(date.getTime());
  val registerForm = Form(
    tuple(
          "user" -> mapping(
            "uid" -> optional(number),
            "email" -> email,
            "password" -> nonEmptyText,
            "created_at" -> ignored(currentTimestamp),
          "updated_at" -> ignored(currentTimestamp)
        )  (User.apply)(User.unapply).verifying("Email already exists.", fields => fields match {
            case user => {
              val result = userDao.findByEmail(user.email)
              !result.isDefined
            }
          }),
        "profile" -> mapping(
          "firstname"->nonEmptyText,
          "lastname"->nonEmptyText,
          "gender" -> ignored(0),
          "user_id" -> ignored(0)
        )(UserProfile.apply)(UserProfile.unapply))
    )
```

How could I have a confirm password field in the binded form? I cant have it in model case class as I use it for my DAO Slick operations too, and would not be worth it to have one more field with similar characteristics.

Thanks

Comment: I believe that you have two use cases here : one is to create users and one is to represent the user across your app. So I would suggest that you split it : create a special case class for user creation, and keep the User and UserProfile to represent your user in your app

Comment: @LouisF. yes, I thought about it, but wont it be against DRY principle?

Comment: I think you are not representing the same information twice : in one hand you want to represent the fact that you want to create a user, on the other you want to represent a user. I believe it's the way to go, otherwise it would lead to clunky hacks (you can already observe this with the ```"created_at" -> ignored(currentTimestamp)```). I think you should try to represent in your types your intention.

Comment: You will also end up with more testable code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i agree with Louis F. above, you should separate the receiving of user data from persistence. you could have a DTO:

```
case class UserData(email: String, password: String, passwordCheck: String)
```

and use `verifying` the same way you do above to ensure that `password == passwordCheck` (so the form only binds if they match). then i would add to the `User` companion object:

```
object User {
  def apply(data: UserData): User = User(None, data.email, data.password, ...)
}
```

note that `fields match { case user => ... }` just renames your reference "fields" to "user" and could be reduced to just the body of the case statement.

Comment: Where should the companion object reside? In models.scala?

Comment: companion objects should reside in the same file as your class definition (more info: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/singleton-objects.html)

Comment: Thanks for your solution